# Do RMI and web services both use a socket connection?

Tags: java, web-services, sockets, rmi, communication-protocol

In another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626799/approach-for-rest-request-with-long-execution-time) I was worried about using a web service that takes a five minutes to complete.  I was thinking about using RMI instead of web services for this use case..

but at the end of the day, do both a web service and RMI use a TCP socket for the underlying connection?  Is there any reason why a web service call taking 5 minutes is less stable than an RMI request taking the same time?

Note that in our case we are talking about internal apps communicating.

---

**Update**: This question stems from me worrying that we'd run into dropped connections or other issues with web services that take 3-5 minutes to complete.  The worry maybe totally irrational - responders to my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626799/approach-for-rest-request-with-long-execution-time) indicated you should be fine if you control both the client and the server.  But I just wanted to understand in more detail why a dropped connection for a 5 minute call is no more likely using a web service implementation than an RMI implementation.  If they both rely on socket connections than that might explain why there is no difference...

Comment: What do you mean by less stable? What do you observe?

Comment: I hadn't observed anything - I was just *obsessing* over possible issues.  Added a clarification to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a single remote call is taking 5 minutes to complete, then it's probably because the operation implementing that call is slow, not because the web service layer itself is slow. If you were to re-wrap the operation with RMI, it'll likely be just as slow.

The performance benefit of RMI over SOAP is only really going to be apparent when you have a large number of operations being called, rather than for the speed of any one operation, simply because RMI is more efficient than SOAP. But it won't magically make a slow operation go faster.

As for your question regarding sockets, yes, RMI and SOAP both use socket-level protocols when you go down far enough (IIOP or JRMP in the case of RMI, HTTP in the case of SOAP). That isn't really relevant to your problem, though.

Answer (score 1):

RMI is mostly used over JRMP (in pure Java context) or IIOP (in non-JVM context), while SOAP messages are usually (but not exclusively) sent over HTTP. All of these three wire protocols use TCP/IP, so in this regard there is no advantage of choosing RMI over a web service.

Comment: RMI isn't used at all in a non-JVM context. RMI/IIOP is used in a J2EE context.