# Responding at arbitrary timing with Jersey on Grizzly using Timer.schedule

Tags: java, jersey, nonblocking, grizzly

all. Thanks in advance.

I am creating a RESTful service with Jersey on Grizzly. In the service, I would like to wait responding to a request for several seconds using "Timer.schedule", instead of using "Thread.sleep", which is a blocking operation.

However, "return" seems to be an only way to respond a request in Jersey. So, I have not figured out the way to do this. If you have any idea doing this, would you please advice me how to do this?

I am using Jersey-1.4 and Grizzly-1.9.32, without Maven.
Thank you very much. Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000439/java-async-rest-web-service-using-jersey), it may be of help to you.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am implementing Grizzly with Servlet to enable comet implementation to realize this. Thank you very much.