# Client progress polling with CPPRestSDK

Tags: c++, rest, asynchronous, casablanca

I have a task which takes a while to execute, and I would like to launch it and broadcast its progress through a Rest request [as described here](http://restful-api-design.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html#asynchronous-requests). I've set up a listener with Client progress polling with CPPRestSDK , but I can't figure out a way of doing this?

I've seen [web::http::http_request::set_progress_handler](https://microsoft.github.io/cpprestsdk/classweb_1_1http_1_1http__request.html#aecb8ba4c46ba84f8135e8e95103c3cea) but I can only see a way to use that if I set up a websocket to push the progress to the client. But I would prefer to monitor progress from the client using polling. A solution [is explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626799/approach-for-rest-request-with-long-execution-time#_=_) but I can't see how I could implement that with this lib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to respond with a URL to a progress listener

```
int progress = 0;
std::string progURL = "http://www.example.com/listener"; 
std::thread progList = std::thread{&ProgressListener, progURL, std::ref(progress)};
web::http::http_response response(web::http::status_codes::Accepted);
response.headers().add("Location", requURL);
request.reply(response);
```

Then start a thread which allows you to host a separate listener.

```
void ProgressListener( std::string progURL, double &progress ){
  web::http::experimental::listener::http_listener progListener(hostURL);
  progListener.support(web::http::methods::GET, [&](web::http::http_request request){
    web::http::http_response response;
    response.set_status_code(web::http::status_codes::OK);
    response.headers().add("Progress", progress); // You can call the header anything pretty much
    request.reply(response);
  }
}
```

And then you need to poll that url with your client, and extract the header data.